# React: Why 'img' is undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this response from my local server:

```
{"total":3,"perPage":5,"page":1,"lastPage":1,
    "data":[{"id":2,
             "category_id":20,
             "title":"Lion",
             "description":"Lion king",
             "img":{"id":1,"filename":"DPp6sNmHqM6oCnBBPyG8wJIW3Z0lRWon.jpeg",
             "original":"Lion.jpg","size":28992,"type":"image/jpeg"}}
]}
```

This is post. I need display post which contains: `category_id`, `title`, `description` and `image`. But now display only `category_id`, `title`, `description`. **And the image itself is not displayed**.

And I try check if my image pass from component Post to component PostDisplay and wrote this line:
`console.log("my data:", props.dataAttribute.img);`

But I got in console:

> `my data: undefined`

#### Why `img` is undefined? I think that if I understand why `img` undefined then I will be able to solve a problem with display of image.

## DisplayPost.js:

```
export default (props) => {
  console.log("my data:", props.dataAttribute.img);     // there img is undefined
 return (
   <div>
     {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <div>
          <div>Title:{item.title}</div>
          <div>Id:{item.category_id}</div>
          <div>Description:{item.description}</div>
          <div>{item.img.filename}</div>    // <-- THIS IS IMAGE
        </div>
      ))}
 </div>
 );
}
```

## Post.js:

```
const Post = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState({
        listImage: [],
    });

 useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); 
  }, []);
    
    async function fetchData() {
        const data = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listImage: data.data,
         }));
    }

  return (
      <div>
        <DisplayPost dataAttribute={value.listImage} />
        <AddPost />
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: item.title , item.category_id and item.description are defined ?

Comment: it's an array then `console.log("image:", props.dataAttribute[0].img.filename);`

Comment: Jérôme Teisseire yes, they defined in : `{props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <div>
          <div>Title:{item.title}</div>
          <div>Id:{item.category_id}</div>
          <div>Description:{item.description}</div>
          <div>{item.img.filename}</div>  
        </div>`

Comment: @xadm When I wrote `console.log` since you advised and on the page an error popped up `TypeError: Cannot read property 'img' of undefined`

Comment: sure, for empty array at start ... `if(props.dataAttribute.length) console.log("image:", props.dataAttribute[0].img.filename);`

Comment: and Add a console.log(value) in `useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); 
    console.log(value);
  }, []);`

Comment: can you read this: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data
maybe that can help you

Answer (score -1):

**Hello,**

Go ahead and destruct that object so that you can work with it on your code. I certainly hope this helps, champion.

```
export default(props) => {
// Destructure the object
let [localObjData] = this.props.dataAttribute;
// access its properties as usual with the .propertyName
console.log(localObjData.img.filename);
return (
<div>
{localObjData.map(item => (
<div>
<div>Title:{item.title}</div>
<div>Id:{item.category_id}</div>
<div>Description:{item.description}</div>
<div>{item.img.filename}</div>    // <-- THIS IS IMAGE
</div>
))}
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: try to remove the props on the map iteraction line, this array is now local